# how to setup zend framework with pdt in mac?

Tags: zend-framework

Hi friends is there a fast way to setup zend framework with eclipse pdt in mac ? I did try with netbeans but sucks big time, even worse is netbeans command line tool which confuses a lot. I also don't like zendeclipse which cost a lot when same feature is free on eclipse pdt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about using Zend Tool with PDT, there is currently no way to do this. Iam using netbeans with my mac, and it works like a charm.